# Join tables in Pyspark with "conditional" conditions

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two tables I want to join:

Table X:

| country | city | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Boston | David |
| USA | Miami | John |
| France | Paris | Peter |

Table Y:

| Country | detail | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | city | Boston | 1 |
| USA | null | null | 2 |
| France | null | null | 3 |

And this is the output I want:

| Country | id | city | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1 | Boston | David |
| USA | 2 | null | David |
| USA | 2 | null | John |
| France | 3 | null | Peter |

The way I get this in SQL is:

```
select country, id, city, user
from X
join Y 
     on x.country = y.country
     and if(y.detail='city', x.city=y.value, TRUE)
```

How can I get in pyspark?

Comment: Column 'y.city' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [x.city, y.id, y.Country, x.country, y.detail, x.user, y.value]

Comment: and if I use y.value, it doesn't get the result you want. I don't get it exactally what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You are right, it was y.value, just edited it. I want to join by the lowest granularity available, if city is available, then join by city and country, if not, join just by country. In SQL this works for me, but I'm trying to do it in Pyspark now

Comment: I run your query using spark sql and i don't get the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with the code below, however I had to select `y.value` and alias it to city in order to get your example output.

```
d1 = [
    ('USA', 'Boston', 'David'),
    ('USA', 'Miami', 'John'),
    ('France', 'Paris', 'Peter')
]

d2 = [
    ('USA', 'city', 'Boston', 1),
    ('USA', None, None, 2),
    ('France', None, None, 3)
]

x = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['country', 'city', 'user'])
y = spark.createDataFrame(d2, ['country', 'detail', 'value', 'id'])

cond = (x.country == y.country) & (when(y.detail == 'city', x.city == y.value).otherwise(F.lit(True)))

x.join(y, on=cond).select(x.country, y.id, y.value.alias('city'), x.user).orderBy('id').show()

+-------+---+------+-----+
|country| id|  city| user|
+-------+---+------+-----+
|    USA|  1|Boston|David|
|    USA|  2|  null|David|
|    USA|  2|  null| John|
| France|  3|  null|Peter|
+-------+---+------+-----+
```